# Enable buttons "Create and Import" in odoo's Tree View

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I am using odoo 8.0. I create a model and a view to manage that model. The code is like this:

*model.py*

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class ServiceLink(osv.Model):
    _name = 'mymodule.servicelink'
    _description = 'Service link'
    _columns =  {
        'link': fields.char('Link')
    }
```

*admin.xml*

```
...
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_view_service_link">
        <field name="name">Service Link</field>
        <field name="res_model">mymodule.servicelink</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
...
```

*ir.model.access.csv*

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
id_01,mymodule.servicelink,model_mymodule_servicelink,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

I imported model(.py) to ____init__.py, admin.xml and ir.model.access.csv to ____openerp__.py >> data.
What I have now: Tree View and Form View for the model worked. However, The button "Create" and "Import" on Tree View don't appear.

My question is: Did I do anything wrong and what could I do to make them appear? Thank you and merry Christmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin.xmk I have to set

```
<field name="view_type">form</field>
```

instead of

```
<field name="view_type">tree</field>
```

reference is [here](https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/2_7_menu_action/7_2_actions/).

Comment: If you do like this you get a table style list and not a tree form. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29657176/636676

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> General Settings

Then Select Allow users to import data from CSV files

Now you will see import option in tree view(s)

Comment: It have selected already, I can see button Create and Import in Tree View of Users and others, but not in the new view that I created.