# Nested Tree View in Odoo v8

Tags: odoo

i have a list of tasks and every task could have 0..* sub tasks.

My model currently looks like this:

```
label = fields.Char(string='Label')
parent_id = fields.Many2one('company.task', string='Super task')
sub_tasks = fields.One2many('company.task', 'parent_id', string='Sub tasks')
#skipped unnecessary parts
```

I want to present the tasks in a hierarchical way, like this:

```
SuperTask1
    SubTask1
    SubTask2
SuperTask2
    SubTask3
...
```

The XML i have so far looks like this:

```
    <!-- Task action window -->
    <record id="action_list_task_complete" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Tasks</field>
        <field name="res_model">company.task</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the first task</p>
        </field>
    </record>

    <!-- Task tree -->
    <record id="task_tree_window_view" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="task_tree_view" />
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_list_task_complete" />
    </record>

    <record id="task_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">company.task.tree</field>
        <field name="model">company.task</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="16"/>
        <field name="field_parent">sub_tasks</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Task list" colors="blue:status=='not_processed';red:status=='delayed'">
                <field name="label"/>
                <field name="sub_tasks"/>
                <field name="parent_id"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

The **field_parent** isn't taken into account when displaying the view. What am I doing wrong here? I looked at other similar questions and and the documentation but all these seem to work only for different versions of odoo.

Anyone an idea?

Regards, F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your action definition, you should set the `view_type` field to `tree` (by default it's `form`):

```
<field name="view_type">tree</field>
```

and remove `view_mode`, as it's ignored when `view_type` is `tree`

It's all very confusing because of bad naming of legacy code which is still present for backward compatibility reasons.

- view_type = form, view_mode = tree is actually the **list** view (the table visualization) which doesn't support real tree navigation (expanding / collpasing the branches)
- view_type = tree, (view_mode is ignored) is the "real" **tree** view

You can read this in the old doc, even though it doesn't make it clear at all https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/2_7_menu_action/7_2_actions/
And you can see as an example the action definition of one of the few tree views in Odoo, [Products by category](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/product/product_view.xml#L528)

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try it out in the next minutes. Regarding your first snippet: Did you mean `name="view_type"` instead of `name="view_mode"` as this is what you stated above? Regards.

Comment: Actually `<field name="view_type">tree</field>` works. Thank you very much. The next problem that it doesn't open a form view when clicking on a record.

Comment: Yes, I meant `view_type` as I described, I edited the snippet now.